# Like Correlation do we have any measurements in Cointegration

Tags: correlation, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

i am new to VEC model

We can test for Cointegration using johansen test but like Correlation do we have any measurements or gauge for good Cointergations , Like we say 90% correlation is good and 50% correlation is moderate.

Comment: Unlike correlation, cointegration is a 0/1 phenomenon: either it is there or it isn't. However, you can measure how quickly the series return to equilibrium when perturbed by a shock. The error correction coefficients reflect that.

Comment: Thank you Richard. So how should i interpret if the measure returns quickly or later for good cointegration

Comment: @Richard: Could you write that as an answer so this resolved?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, I do not have time to respond to the comment after the answer, thus I have not done as you suggest. But I can still copy the first comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike correlation, cointegration is a 0/1 phenomenon: either it is there or it isn't. However, you can measure how quickly the series return to equilibrium when perturbed by a shock. The error correction coefficients reflect that.